# Issues with Select Option loop with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, select-options

I am using jQuery to loop through many Select Option html elements, and I can get it to work one at a time, but I'm having difficulty accessing the data if it is stored in a jQuery element.

For example I have these 2 Select html elements

`var lList = $(".p1_lSelect");`

`var rList = $(".p1_rSelect");`

I can get my desired output with the following

```
$(".p1_lSelect option:selected").each(function() {
    selected = $(this).text(); //selected == "p1_lSelect_Data"
    console.log(selected);
});

$(".p1_rSelect option:selected").each(function() {
    selected = $(this).text(); //selected == "p1_rSelect_Data"
    console.log(selected);
});

//Console logs .p1_lSelect_Data and .p1_rSelect_Data as expected
```

What I would like is something similar to the following so that I can change which list I'm feeding into the loop

```
function foo(){
    var lList = $(".p1_lSelect");
    var rList = $(".p1_rSelect");
    bar(lList);
    bar(rList);
}

function bar(list){
    $("list option:selected").each(function() {
        selected = $(this).text();
        console.log(selected);
    });
    //Console log does not print
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following code based on your structure:

```
function foo(){
    var lList = $(".p1_lSelect");
    var rList = $(".p1_rSelect");
    bar(lList);
    bar(rList);
}

function bar(list){
    $(list).find("option:selected").each(function() {
        selected = $(this).text();
        console.log(selected);
    });
    //Console log does not print
}
```

Comment: I'll try this too seems like it'll be easier to implement here. Would there be any immediate benefit to using template literals as suggested by @Majed Badawi rather than the find method?

Comment: You can use children() method instead of find() method.

Comment: and in this example, list parameter is object, so I think you can't use template literals if you want deliver object parameter.

Comment: if you want to use template literals, you have to deliver class name as parameter of function bar as @Majed did.

Comment: Okay sounds like it's more trouble than it's worth in this particular case as the find method worked just fine. I don't know anything about template literals, so I'm just going to have to read up on them in the meantime. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the name of the list and append it to the selector as follows:

```
function foo(){
    bar("p1_lSelect");
    bar("p1_rSelect");
}

function bar(list){
    $(`.${list} option:selected`).each(function() {
        selected = $(this).text();
        console.log(selected);
    });
    //Console log does not print
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot, could you tell me what the curly braces you're using here are called in jQuery, I'd like to look more into how it works

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use the `find()` method:

```
function bar(list) {
    list.find("option:selected").each(function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
});
```